# Excel mod function rounding error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am testing multiples of 0.4 in Excel.

> =MOD(1.2;0.4)

returns 0.4, when it should returns zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that Excel internally works with floating point numbers.

That means that the 0.4 is internally represented as a bit sequence to the right from the decimal point, which represent 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc., up to about 1/(2^31).

Therefore, anything that is *not* an integer (and is not *exactly* representable with the fractions listed above) has a rounding error associated with it; this applies to every step of a calculation too.

`MOD(*,0.4)` is just one example to show that off (a rather blatant one, I give you that).

Basically, **you cannot reliably use `MOD` with non-integers as the second parameter**. You need to multiply and divide your data accordingly up if that is an option (like `=MOD(10*x;10*m)/10`), or code the MOD-formula yourself: `=x-INT(x/m)*m`.

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. The first formula works, but the latter no.